# Loading bar when axios getting/posting request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progress-bar

I am trying to make a loading bar on my project using [Vue ProgressBar](http://hilongjw.github.io/vue-progressbar/index.html), and it works on my route, and that does not work when Axios is getting or posting the request.

This is my project code when i start the loading bar,

```
<script>
    import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
    import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue';
    export default {
        components: {
            'editor': Editor
        },
        title() {
            return 'Stock group data';
        },
        data() {
            return {
                stockgroup: {},
                user: {},
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.$Progress.start();
            this.loadDataWarehouse();
            this.loadUser();
            this.$Progress.finish();
        },
        methods: {
            async loadDataWarehouse() {
                const response = await axios.get('/api/stock-group/' + this.$route.params.id);
                this.stockgroup = response.data;
            },
            async loadUser() {
                const resp = await axios.get('/api/contact-list');
                this.user = resp.data;
            },
        },
    }

</script>
```

the `this.$Progress.start()` line is where the loading bar is executed.

But before I make it like this, I already read the documentation that we must add code on our default Vue app. I mean like `App.vue`

So i add this code to my `App.vue`
[image: Appvue]

but when I running it and request to getting data, I don't know why it doesn't show the loading bar.
You can see it here.

[image: it should be existed loader bar]

Is anyone can help me?
Please...

Comment: Please don't add code as screenshots. Its difficult to read and understand when you add code as a screenshot

Comment: Okay sir, my bad.
Thank you sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want the progressbar showing on every request without needed to repeating the start and finish code. you can try to use `axios interceptor`

```js
this.axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    this.$Progress.start();
    return config;
});
this.axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        this.$Progress.finish();
        return Promise.resolve(response);
    },
    (error) => {
        this.$Progress.finish();
        return Promise.reject(error);
    },
);
```

Comment: Where can i add it sir? On main.php or app.jss sir?

Comment: you can add it on created lifecycle in app.vue or even on your main.js file but not using the `this` keyword but using the axios itself instead

Comment: Will try this sir.
And I will update accept this answer later sir.
Thank you sir for helping me.. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You are looking past the `async` functions you are calling!

In-fact what you are doing is, showing the progress bar and hiding it soon after calling two `async` functions.

You have two options here.

1. Make the `hook` async and `await` inside.

   ```
   created: async () => {
    this.$Progress.start();
    // wait for the async to finish
    await this.loadDataWarehouse();
    await this.loadUser();
    // then hide the progress bar
    this.$Progress.finish();
   },
   ```

OR

2. Push both inside a `promises` array and wait- this is not as elegant in terms of readability but could be better in terms of performance because it does not wait for the first promise to return to execute the second promise unlike in option 1.

   ```
   created: () => {
    // promises array
    let promises = [];
    // this context
    const self = this;
    this.$Progress.start();
    // push into the array
    promises.push(this.loadDataWarehouse());
    promises.push(this.loadUser());
    // then hide the progress bar
    Promise.all(promises).then(()=>{
      self.$Progress.finish();
    })
   },
   ```

Comment: Wow.. Great sir... 
It worked for me sir.. Thank you sir...